# how do I solve this arithmetic series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this arithmetic series $3+7+11+...+35+39$ to solve. So I see that there is a difference by 4 between the numbers and that there is a total of 9 terms.

I plug these values in the following equation $S = 4 \cdot \frac{9(9+1)}{2}$. This results to 180 and that is not the correct result.

Can anyone explain what I did wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: By steps, if you mean "terms" in the sequence, then you have $10$ terms, not $9$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

You have an arithmetic progression and so you want to compute $$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n(a+i d)$$ which, if you remember, equal to $$S_n=\frac{1}{2} (n+1) (2 a+d n)$$ Using your numbers, $a=3$, $d=4$,$n=9$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 
$$\frac{10(3+39)}{2}=210$$
where $10$ is the number of the terms, $3$ is the first term, $39$ is the last term.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

$$S_{n} = n \cdot \frac{a_{0}+a_{n}}{2}$$

We have

$a_{0} = 3$

$a_{n} = 39$

$n = 10$

Answer (score 0):

I will use another method. There are actually 10 terms in the series. Also, notice that 1st + last term = 42, similarly, 2nd + 2nd last term = 42, and so on. Since there are 5 pairs. The answer is $42\times5 = 210$.